# Munin mysql plugin silently fails

Tags: mysql, munin

I installed [this Munin MySQL plugin](https://github.com/kjellm/munin-mysql) on a RHEL 6 machine and I'm experiencing a strange behavior.

I'm not getting any data in the Munin web page (the Categories list does not show a *mysql* link), but I'm not receiving any error neither. 
All other graphs (*disk*, *processes*, *system*, etc) work fine.

`munin-run mysql` and `munin-run mysql config` print absolutely no output and exit with zero status. Running `munin-run` with any other plugin works fine.

The Munin logfile shows no error:

```
2016/04/20-14:40:01 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[10.10.10.20]:33967" Local: "[10.10.10.15]:4949"
2016/04/20-14:45:02 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[10.10.10.20]:49531" Local: "[10.10.10.15]:4949"
2016/04/20-14:50:02 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[10.10.10.20]:59469" Local: "[10.10.10.15]:4949"
```

The mysql logs show no error neither.

What might be wrong with it?

I installed the same plugin a couple months ago on a CentOS 7 machine in pretty much the same way and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.  The autoconf option of the plugin reported this error:

```
[root@linuxbox ~]# /usr/share/munin/plugins/mysql_ autoconf
no (DBI connect('mysql;mysql_connect_timeout=5','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO))
```

Then I realized `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node` was missing the mysql plugin configuration:

```
[mysql*]
user root
group wheel
env.mysqladmin /usr/bin/mysqladmin
env.mysqlopts -umunin -pp4ssw0rd
```

where *munin* is the MySQL user (with password *p4ssw0rd*) that fetches the data from the MySQL server.

Once this was put in place, the plugin started working.

Edit: It might be necessary to check that `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/mysql.conf` contains the correct credentials as well.